# create dynamic table containing radiobutton list asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to ask a question about dynamic table on asp.net c#
i want to make a dynamic table but on this table i want to insert radiobutton on every table row and column.
table create based on user input. if user input row 3 and column 3 system can display row length is 3 and column length is 3

input from user is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="rows" runat="server" MaxLength="20" Width="272px" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="column" runat="server" MaxLength="20" Width="272px" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="create" runat="server" Text="create table" CssClass="art-button" OnClick="create_Click" />
```

then the result is sistem display a table with row as long as user input on rows.textbox and column as long as column.textbox and on every rows and column has one radiobutton

anyone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.I think this is what you looking for.

```
 protected void create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Table dynamicTable = new Table();
    TableRow Row;
    TableCell Cell;
    int rowno=int.Parse(rows.Text);
    int cols=int.Parse(column.Text);
    for (int row = 0; row < rowno; row++)
    {
        Row = new TableRow();
        dynamicTable.Rows.Add(Row);

        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            Cell = new TableCell();
            // adding radiobutton
            RadioButton rad = new RadioButton();
            rad.ID = "rad_" + col.ToString();
            Cell.Controls.Add(rad);
            Row.Cells.Add(Cell);
        }
    }
}
```

It will create dynamic table with radio button as user input.

Comment: i must create table first or not, like <table id="tableContent" border="1" runat="server"></table>

Comment: i got what's your code mean and its done thanks, but where did i put the value or ID of radiobutton? what i supose to do if display of table has  rows and column like excel(ex: A1,A2, etc)? thanks before

Comment: i am happy that it helps you..
For your next query::i am not getting what you are asking.can you be more clear?

Comment: when table create successfully then i choose one of radiobutton, what i supose to do if i want to got the value of radiobutton?
because i want to insert the value of radiobutton to my database

Comment: if i want to do the same thing inside a js file, how should i Proceed?

Comment: @PranavRaj then you need to google it or ask new question with your problems!